# How to fix Argument of type '() => AbstractControl[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'array[]'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have chosen to use reactive forms for my form and I have a list of checkboxes to check, and I'm trying to use the `FormArray` to do this, however when I call my function in my Ng for , I got this error. Is it possible to change the `AbstractControl` type or do I have to modify the parameters of my array?

`HTML`

```html
<tr class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;" [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let engin of getControls() | appFilter: searchText; let i = index" >
            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked" [(ngModel)]="engin.isSelected" #fEngins name="list_engins[]"  value="{{engin.identifiant}}"
        (change)="isAllSelected()"/>
            <td>{{engin.num_facade}}</td>
            <td>{{engin.num_immatriculation_ef}}</td>
        </tr>
```

`component.ts`

```js
getControls() {
    
    return (this.form.get('engins') as FormArray).controls;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
getControls(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('engins') as FormArray;
}
```

Alternative, you can modify your code with some trick to be:

```
get controls(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('engins') as FormArray;
}
```

and usage:

```
*ngFor="let engin of controls.control"
```

Comment: yes, it works with the alternative, thanks

Comment: You welcome, hope you enjoy.